# using views argument in the view tpl.php file

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

i am a newby to drupal.
here is my problem:
on my main page.tpl.php i have this code lines:

"if ( $is_front == TRUE ) {

print views_embed_view('all_product_by_type_thin', "default", "canon");

print views_embed_view('all_product_by_type_thin', "default", "Nikon");

}"

as you can see, in case of the front page i print the "all_product_by_type_thin" view while sending parameter "cannon" and "nikon"

the result of the all_product_by_type_thin view is altered inside the views-view-unformatted--all_product_by_type_thin.tpl.php file.
in that file i am wrapping the view results in all kind of divs.
what i need to do though, and cant figure out a way to do it, is get the argument i sent the view "canon" or "nikon" inside the php code of views-view-unformatted--all_product_by_type_thin.tpl.php
any idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your Views theme file ie. `views-view-unformatted--all_product_by_type_thin.tpl.php` you should have access to the `$view` object.

One of the attributes of this object will contain the arguments passed to the view. You can do a `print_r` and find this attribute and hence, the arguments.